# SELECT only row where all other activity are completed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with column called , ID,Activity,Activity_type,Activity Status.

Here activity status 11 = Completed, 12 = Incomplete.

Each ID is associated with activity type call1,call2,email1,email2 and text1. I only want to query all the ID with activity Text1 with "Activity Status"=12  when all other "Activity Status" related to that ID = 11.

In the example I would like to get output of Text1 with ID 10 as ID 11 still has email 2 with activity status 12. Any help on this is much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` should be a working solution, but your question probably has two possible answers:

- case, when `"Activity Status" = 12` and all *other (all the rest)* `"Activity Status" = 11`
- case, when `"Activity Status" = 12` and all *other (all possible four)* `"Activity Status" = 11`

Input:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data 
(
    ID int,
    Activity varchar(10),
    Activity_type int,
    Activity_status int
)
INSERT INTO #Data
    (ID, Activity, Activity_type, Activity_status)
VALUES
    (10, 'call1',  10893, 11),
    (10, 'call2',  10894, 11),
    (10, 'email1', 10895, 11),
    (10, 'email2', 10896, 11),
    (10, 'text1',  10897, 12),
    (11, 'call1',  10893, 11),
    (11, 'call2',  10894, 11),
    (11, 'email1', 10895, 11),
    (11, 'email2', 10896, 12),
    (11, 'text1',  10897, 12)
```

T-SQL (for all the rest):

```
SELECT ID
FROM #Data
GROUP BY ID
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN Activity = 'text1' AND Activity_status = 12 THEN 1 END) = 1 AND
    SUM(1) - SUM(CASE WHEN Activity <> 'text1' AND Activity_status = 11 THEN 1 END) = 1
```

T-SQL (for all possible four):

```
SELECT ID
FROM #Data
GROUP BY ID
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN Activity = 'text1' AND Activity_status = 12 THEN 1 END) = 1 AND
    SUM(CASE WHEN Activity IN ('call1', 'call2', 'email1', 'email2') AND Activity_status = 11 THEN 1 END) = 4
```

Output:

```
---
ID
---
10
```

Comment: Hi Zhorov, Thank you so much , it worked, I have used SELECT ID
FROM #Data
GROUP BY ID
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN Activity = 'text1' AND Activity_status = 12 THEN 1 END) = 1 AND
    SUM(1) - SUM(CASE WHEN Activity <> 'text1' AND Activity_status = 11 THEN 1 END) = 1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having sum(case when activity = 'Text1' and activity_status = 12 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when activity <> 'Text1' and activity_status <> 11 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i have not getting the expected result. As per the above table the query is also bringing ID 11

Comment: @Biswa . . . The only way I can interpret the logic you describe and this statement "In the example I would like to get output of Text1 with ID 10 as ID 11 still has email 2 with activity status 12" is that you only want ID 10.

Comment: Yes thats what i want. Only ID 10 as ID 10 has all the activity status= 11 but in case of ID 11 not all the activity status is completed as email 2 still has activity status 12

Comment: @Biswa . . . And this query should only be returning ID 10.  If you are seeing other results, please set up a db<>fiddle.

Comment: sorry brother, but i'm new to SQL what does db<>fiddle means

Comment: It's a hosted instance of SQL Server that you can populate with sample data to show your issue, and that it is reproducible. Here's one: https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: It doesnt allow me to create a table as its been changed to paid version. any alternative